# Filter/Prevent client publishing behavior to rooms in Faye

Tags: publish-subscribe, faye, bayeux

I was looking at using Faye for a project I've been working on since socket.io has been causing me trouble.  I set up and played with some of the examples on their github and found that clients can publish straight to whatever room they are connected to.  This is different behavior than what I would like. I want to limit client behavior in certain rooms to where they cannot publish at all but the server will periodically send data to the room updating them all on new information (Basically a strict subscribe behavior on certain rooms).  Is this type of behavior possible with Faye or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [CometD](http://cometd.org), you can fine tune the behaviour you want.

You have available a `SecurityPolicy` that allow you to control coarsely the publish authorizations, and channel `Authorizers` that allow you to control finely the publish authorizations (among others).

Have a read at the `SecurityPolicy` [documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_authorization), and at the `Authorizers` [documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_authorizers).

The Bayeux protocol has been designed by the CometD project where you can find the latest [specification](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#bayeux).

Have also a look at the [CometD tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/), if you want to get started with CometD.